# How to I construct a pipe in Linux to sort python files from other files on date and name?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Currently I'm learning about pipes. I want to achieve the following:

> Construct a shell pipeline that finds all files with extension “.py”in
> your homedir, sort on size and print both size, date and name using 1)
> find, tr, awk/cut and 2) ls/sort.

I succeeded in separating the python files from the other files with:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py"
```

But I don't know how to proceed to sort on the other criteria. I actually think that what I did is wrong since redirecting statements usually begin with `cat ... |`

Question: How do I construct a shell pipeline that finds all files with extension .py, sorts them on size and prints size, date and name?

Ter

Comment: Start with http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003

Comment: And http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/119 if you're using `cat` a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the link! But how do you achieve the above stated goal with cat in a piped way? @Shawn

Comment: You don't need `cat` for this.

Comment: Okay, but could you please give an example on how to sort on filetype and size and print size/date/name? I don't see in the links an example on how to do those things in one command. @Shawn

Comment: Consider: `stat --printf="%s\t%y\t%n\0" ~/*.py | sort -z -k1,1n | tr "\0" "\n"`